# count when at least one string exist in data unix using awk/sed

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a data as below in vi editor with blank lines. i want to 
search for "aaaa|bbbb|cccc" in each an every block.

If at least one of them (either of "aaaa" , "bbbb" , "cccc") is present in block i need to count the block. My output should be number of blocks which contains at least one of them.

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc

aaaa
bbbb

cccc
aaaa

xxxx
yyyy

aaaa
xxxx

xxxx
zzzz
yyyy

yyyy
zzzz
bbbb

bbbb
yyyy
```

In the above example, output is 6.

How can I achieve this goal ?

Comment: `grep  "aaaa|bbbb|cccc" | wc -l`

Comment: Are you forced to use awk and sed, or can you use for instance grep ?

Comment: This is why formatting is important. My solution is crap, but it looked good before you edited the post.

Comment: On that note, revert your edits, select the text and click on the button that says "code" (the curly braces) please.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,using grep also fine. But i need to count entire block as one, if i find at least one in "aaaa","bbbb","cccc"

Comment: Edited your input example from first revision, have a look at it to follow @MadPhysicist advice in the future

Comment: @Tensibai. Thanks. I was literally in the middle of making that edit the easy way when OP beat me to it with his travesty. Kinda killed my spirit for the thing.

Comment: For the records, keyboard shortcut for code formatting is ctrl+k :)

Comment: @Tensibai. Thanks. I didn't know that. I think you may have saved hours of my life in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS= '/aaaa|bbbb|cccc/{c++} END{print c}' filewithfixedformat

6
```

Setting `RS=` will define blocks separated by blank lines as records and script counts the records where the condition is met.

Comment: Wow. A great example of where `awk` is really the best solution, hands down. Also, wish I could give a second thumbs up just for `filewithfixedformat`.

Comment: Does it work for more search filters (ex:27) ? i have tried with 27 search filters

Comment: @srinivas when you tried with 27 filters, did it work or not? I would have thought that the result of performing that experiment would answer your own question.

Comment: same answer in perl: `perl -00 -nE '$c++ if /aaaa|bbbb|cccc/}{say $c'`